# Swift tvOS - TabBar Trailing Accessory View Focus

Tags: swift, tvos

The tabbar has a `trailingAccessoryView` that the documentation indicates can be used for some user actions. However, while I can put a view inside this accessory view, it does not get the focus at any point. Is there a means to allow this view to get the focus when swiping right from the tabbar?

```
let symbolConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 30, weight: .bold, scale: .large)
        let guideButton = UIButton()
        guideButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "list.bullet", withConfiguration: symbolConfig), for: .normal)
        guideButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(test), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
        guideButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tabBar.trailingAccessoryView.addSubview(guideButton)
        guideButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.trailingAccessoryView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        guideButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.trailingAccessoryView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

As a note, I have tried setting: `tabBar.trailingAccessoryView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

While not an exact answer, I wound up getting around this issue by adding the button to the tabbar's view rather than to the trailingAccessoryView. Not clear why the accessory view wouldn't work, but this does turn out to be a workable answer that does the job just as well.